# Access Control Problem

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, access-control

I am developing an access control library for my project and I am looking to the best solution to do this:

I am getting all my access list from database to an array. In result it looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    '*' => array('administrator' => TRUE),
    'frontend/*' => array(
        'user' => TRUE,
        'unregistered' => TRUE
        ),
    'backend/*' => array(
        'user' => FALSE,
        'unregistered' => FALSE
    ),
    'backend/user/*' => array(
        'moderator' => FALSE,
        'supermoderator' => TRUE,
    ),
    'backend/article/*' => array(
        'supermoderator' => TRUE
    ),
    'backend/article/add/new' => array(
        'moderator' => TRUE
    )
);
```

The " * " means this user has access all of that related options backend/article/* means that group have access to all article options (article/add, article/remove, ...).

As you see the there is no item in `backend/article/add` for supermoderator but it has the master access to all article pages.

What is the best way to check this? I tried `array_walk()` but I guess it wont help me.

Thank you for advices...

I can share my whole code if you want.

*** Edit ***

Am I storing wrong? If you have the better solution to store it I will be happy to hear it.

Thank you for any advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

lets say the user trying to access `backend/article/add/new` and this user in the supermoderator group. So I need to look for `backend/*`, `backend/article/*`, `backend/article/add/*`. `array_slice()` and `for()` enough for this:

I am using CodeIgniter by the way. I modified it a little bit to seperate frontend and backend controllers. I am not using `application/controller` directory. I am using `application/backend` and `application/frontend` directories for controllers.

So an uri pattern is this: `http://site.com/[backend]*/[directory]*/class/method`

```
// This is the page that user trying to reach
$requested_page = "backend/article/add/new";

// pharsing...
$x = explode('/', $requested_page);

// this is needed to cut last 3, 2, 1 items of $x
$i = count($x) > 3 ? -4 : -count($x);

for (; $i < 0; $i++) {
    $resource = implode('/', array_slice($x, 0, $i)) . '/*';
    // echoing for debug
    echo $resource;
}

// Outputs:
// backend/*
// backend/article/*
// backend/article/add/*
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what this is going to be a complex algorithm, a simple `array_walk` wont do. Unless someone is feeling particularly generous and will write one for you, I suggest you **hire** a programmer.

---

> Am I storing wrong? If you have the better solution to store it I will be happy to hear it.

It totally depends on your algorithm. You can probably write one that uses your current data format. You can also probably write a simpler one if you change your data format. But what your data format should look like then, well, that's a job for a programmer.

Comment: yea I can do it with explode the resources and check it. I do not need a programmer. But since I do not know all php functions very well, I thinked some coders could suggest me functions.

Comment: You don't particularly need any PHP functions besides perhaps `foreach`, `explode` and `in_array` but these functions are common in any language so your argument is completely beside the point. You need an algorithm.

Comment: what about storing them? I am using resource => group relationship. does the group => resource relationship will be more helpfull?

Answer (score 0):

```
function userHasPermissions($permissionsArray, $user, $path) {
    // Check exact
    if(isset($permissionsArray[$path]) &&
       isset($permissionsArray[$path][$user])) {
        return $permissionsArray[$path][$user];
    }

    // Check lower and lower
    $partArr = explode('/', $path);
    for($i = substr_count($path, '/'); $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if($i > 0) {
            $choppedPartArr = array_slice($partArr, 0, $i);
            $newPath = implode($choppedPartArr, '/') . '/*';
        } else {
            $newPath = '*';
        }

        if(isset($permissionsArray[$newPath]) &&
           isset($permissionsArray[$newPath][$user])) {
            return $permissionsArray[$newPath][$user];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo "Result: " . (userHasPermissions($array, 'supermoderator', 'backend/article/add') ? "true" : "false");
```

Note that 'backend/article' will return false for 'supermoderator' since 'backend/article/*' does not match it. To change this, simply change `$i = substr_count($path, '/');` to `$i = substr_count($path, '/')+1;`.